# Abstract Class as ref compiler error

Tags: c#, abstract-class, ref

So I've created a framework for settings in my application, all been good until I came across this little roadbump.

In the abstract base class I have this:

```
public abstract class SettingsBase
{
    public event SettingsChangedEventHandler SettingsChanged;

    public void NotifyChange() { NotifyChange(this); }

    private void NotifyChange(object sender, EventArgs args = null) 
    { 
        SettingsChanged?.Invoke(this); 
    }

    protected void OnSetChildSettings(ref SettingsBase settings, SettingsBase value)
    {
        if (Equals(settings, value)) return;
        if (settings != null) settings.SettingsChanged -= NotifyChange;
        settings = value;
        if (settings != null) settings.SettingsChanged += NotifyChange;
    }
}
```

Which is a cut down version showing just the code that's causing me grief.

And this in one implementation:

```
public class ChildSettings : SettingsBase { }
```

And here is the where the compiler error shows up:

```
public class ParentSettings : SettingsBase
{
    private ChildSettings _childSettings;

    public ChildSettings ChildSettings
    {
        get { return _childSettings; }
        set { OnSetChildSettings(ref _childSettings, value); }
    }
}
```

It's driving me mad, saying: "The 'ref' parameter type doesn't match parameter type". It's definitely a SettingsBase, do I have do a cast? Do I have to do template with constraints? This is very poor of C# to not work if so, though maybe I am just spoiled after using it for a few years now.

Edit - This works:

```
protected void OnSetChildSettings<T>(ref T settings, T value) where T : SettingsBase
{
    if (Equals(settings, value)) return;
    if (settings != null) settings.SettingsChanged -= NotifyChange;
    settings = value;
    if (settings != null) settings.SettingsChanged += NotifyChange;
}
```

Although I have a working solution I still want to understand what was wrong and why, so answers are still greatly appreciated.

Edit2 - Fixed naming, I just changed it to simply things for this question and missed some. Thanks :)

Comment: How is `_loadingManagerSettings` defined?

Comment: You haven't provided the declaration for the variable in question (i.e. `_loadingManagerSettings`), so there's no way to say for sure why you are getting the error.  It's pretty clear the variable's type isn't `SettingsBase` though.

Comment: Just an error changing names for the question, I left some with the original naming by accident, thanks for noticing, I have fixed it since.